# wp_redirect doesn't redirect to the desired URL

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to perform a simple page redirection for my wordpress website.

The following code doesn't work when added in the functions.php file:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect2' );
function redirect2() {
if (is_page('http://mywebsite.com/')) {$url_1 = 'http://www.google.com'; wp_redirect($url_1); die();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: did you `init` your action?

Comment: `is_page()` dont accept urls. use id, slug: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: Thanks problem solved, I also needed to give a priority.